# generating integer sequences

Tags: r

How would I take the even values from 18 to 40 and repeat the sequence until I have 30 observations?

i.e. (18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, …40, 18, 20, 22, 24, …40, 18, …)

Answer (score 6):

We may use `rep` with `seq` i.e. `seq` to return the sequencees from 18 to 40 in intervals of 2 and then `rep`licate the vector derived from `seq` to recycle till the `length` of the replicated vector reaches 30

```
rep(seq(18, 40, by = 2), length.out = 30)
```

Or as @I_O commented (there will be a warning message as the lengths are not the same)

```
integer(30) + 9:20 * 2
```

-output

```
[1] 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 18 20 22 24 26 28
```

Comment: quick'n'dirty: `rep(9:20*2, 20) %>% head(30)`

Comment: yet another way, somewhat unorthodox: `vector('integer',30) + 9:20 * 2`

Answer (score 5):

A short alternative using modular math:

```r
18 + 2 * (0:29 %% 12)
#>  [1] 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 18 20 22 24 26 28 30 32 34 36
#> [23] 38 40 18 20 22 24 26 28
```